Nuxt - CSP of defined css-files has no nonce and fails
Issue:
I have multiple css files which are defined in the nuxt.config.ts. I have the nuxt-security with strict enabled.
The issue i have is that the CSP fails cause the content of these css-files is added in the browser via .... So there is no nonce or so on.
I then expanded the style-src to all possible variations, but based on the given structure the inline is always ignored - and it would not solve the original issue.
What i dont understand is why these files are not handled correct with a none in nuxt like everything. Additionally the font-integration which is done by nuxt/fonts is also in this style-block without a nonce.

Additional Information
package.json - dependencies
"nuxt": "^3.14.0",
"@nuxt/fonts": "^0.10.2",
"nuxt-security": "^2.1.1",

nust.config.ty - styles
css: [
    '@/assets/css/tailwind.css',
    '@/assets/css/fileA.scss',
    '@/assets/css/fileB.scss',
    '@/assets/css/fileC.scss',
],

nuxt.config.ts - Security
security: {
    strict: true,
    headers: {
        contentSecurityPolicy: {
            'style-src': ["'self'", "https:", "'nonce-{{nonce}}'", "'unsafe-hashes'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        },
        permissionsPolicy: false,
    },
}

Browser CSP-Issue

